# Connecting ember js application with react host : microfrontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ember.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I was trying to connect different frontend tech together in a React host using microfrontend.

I managed to connect react, vue, VanillaJS application to the React host, but i am not able to wrap my head around Ember JS, since vue, Vanilla were not framekwork, it was easy to connect them using webpack ModuleFederationPlugin.

I tried searching it over internet couldn't find any help, Is it possible to connect Ember JS application to a react based host environment(using module federation) ??

If yes would like to see an example if it's available online. (github or sandbox links)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these docs: [Embedding Applications](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/)

The gist is that on the application's rootElement property, you can set a dom selector:
[image: here, rootElement is set to the value '#app' on the Application instance in app/app.js]

There are more steps as well, but this should get you started.

Kind of a caveat though, building ember projects currently requires the `ember-cli`, and I don't know if it'd be possible to "just use a webpack plugin", unless you pre-build the ember app before building your host app.